# Jar Manifest help: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable-jar, manifest.mf

Trying to create an executable jar file - but I can't seem to get the manifest correct

manifest file "tdms.mf"

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: rackserials.tdms
```

Jar creation

```
jar cfvm rackserials.jar tdms.mf  *.class assetdata.xlsx
added manifest
adding: Asset.class(in = 10946) (out= 3918)(deflated 64%)
adding: TDMSConnection.class(in = 2599) (out= 1372)(deflated 47%)
adding: tdms.class(in = 13402) (out= 6732)(deflated 49%)
adding: assetdata.xlsx(in = 23998) (out= 20987)(deflated 12%)
```

Running this command from within Directory called "tdms" contents:

```
Asset.class
TDMSConnection.class
tdms.class **where my main is located**
tdms.mf
assetdata.xlsx
```

CLI

```
java -jar rackserials.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class rackserials.tdms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory structure inside the JAR file must match the package structure of your classes, and the `Main-Class` attribute must be set to the fully-qualified name of the class that contains the `public static void main(String[] args)` method that is the entry point of your application.

Are your classes in the package `rackserials`? Then the `*.class` files inside the JAR file must be in a directory named `rackserials`, and not in the root directory of the JAR file.

You can list the content of a JAR file using `jar tvf rackserials.jar`. It should look like this:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
rackserials/tdms.class
(whatever other files)
```

See [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials for all the details of creating JAR files and working with manifest files to create an executable JAR.

Comment: Thank you Jesper - this got me on the right track. The classes are in the package rack serials but I was attempting to make my JAR file from within the directory they were all contained within as well - so the classpath was wrong. Looking at how I could run using java rackserials.tdms got me thinking and I arrived to the same conclusion you posted here. Thanks again